# How to measure Sample Rate?

Tags: import, sound

How do I measure the sample rate of an imported file in *Mathematica*?

I imported the WAV file:

```
solo = Import["solo.wav"]
```

When I wrote:

```
SampleRate[solo]
```

I received: [image: Sound]

But I just need a number like `28.000` to be returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
solo = Import[ "ExampleData/rule30.wav" ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[solo, (SampledSoundFunction | SampledSoundList)[__, r_] :>  r, Infinity][[1]]
```

> 44100

Answer (score 12):

One can also use `Import[]` to directly query the *.wav file's sample rate, like so:

```
Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav", "SampleRate"]
   44100
```

Answer (score 6):

The sample rate is the second element in solo. The first element (i.e., solo[[1, 1]]) is the waveform data.

```
solo = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"];
solo[[1, 2]]

44100
```

Comment: Doesn't work on new Mathematica 11.2

Answer (score 2):

For Mathematica 11:

```
AudioSampleRate[myAudio]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate@Audio@solo
(*44100*)
```

Comment: This doesn't work